# Problem balancing two column memoir

Tags: vertical-alignment, memoir, two-column

I have a problem using `\balance` on this document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twocolumn]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{balance}

\balance

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

I have no problem with `book` and `article`, but with `memoir` document class the first line of text is moved down, like in the the MWE:

[image: the problem]

I can't use `multicols` because it can not handle float on single column. I'm using `pdflatex` on Fedora 17. Anyone have some suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

With `article` instead of `memoir`, the `balance` package seems to cause *different* problems -- there's an empty line at the bottom of the first column. Besides that (and as in your example), the line-spacing after the first line of the second column is wrong.

Solution: Use the [`flushend`](http://ctan.org/pkg/flushend) package instead. (Note that, according to the [TeX FAQ](http://texfaq.org/FAQ-balance), it's "a dangerous piece of code".)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twocolumn]{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{flushend}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```